# Android Unable to print on WiFi Printer using socket connection

Tags: android, printing, socket.io

I have an Android application and one of the features is to connect to a `printer` through `WiFi`.

I have tried to use Socket connection to connect HP printer through wifi to print a string. But unfortunately, the printer cannot print anything, only show waiting for printing in the printer screen.

The problem is the Android application can connect to this `HP` printer because the printer changes the status from ready for printing to printing the document, but there is no any further response from the printer.

Does anyone know what is wrong with this issue? Because of the HP printer? or Socket statement

Thanks in advance

please click the following links to check the core function code

[1. This is my socket connect function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmTKy.png)

[2. This method is used to send a message to the printer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHpov.png)

Comment: show your effort, where is your code?

Comment: Hi, I have added my core functions code

Comment: Did you get any solution?